# Function To Repeat The Last Command With a Substitution

Tags: zsh

I normally change part of the previous command using

```
!!:gs/Change/ChangeTo
```

To simplify I have created a function

```
funciton re() {
    !!:gs/$1/$2
}
```

Now the output is like following

```
[~/Desktop]$ print -P '\033[34mThis is the same color as in your solarized palette\033[0m'
This is the same color as in your solarized palette
[~/Desktop]$ !!:gs/34/35                                                                
[~/Desktop]$ print -P '\033[35mThis is the same color as in your solarized palette\033[0m'
This is the same color as in your solarized palette
[~/Desktop]$ re 35 36                                                                   
re:1: no such file or directory: !!:gs/35/36
[~/Desktop]✕127$
```

So, it is giving error `re:1: no such file or directory: !!:gs/35/36` when I am invoking the function.

I have also tried

```
funciton re() {
    ^$1^$2^:G
}
```

It says command not found

```
[~/Desktop]$ re 35 36
^35^36^:G: command not found
[~/Desktop]✕127$
```

What might be the solution here?

Comment: History references, where applicable, are expanded as soon as the line containing them is entered. If you define the function at the command prompt, you should get a bad substitution error (or some effect) as soon as you enter that line, before you even complete the function definition. If you are sourcing from a file, it appears that the history expansion is suppressed (though I can't find a good reference for that assertion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the `fc` command. After a little experimentation:

```
re() { fc -e - "$1=$2"; }
```

Then:

```
$ echo foo bar
foo bar
$ re bar qux
echo foo qux
foo qux
```

I'm not sure how to suppress the edited command from being printed, if that's important for you.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman),
I found that

```
re 2>/dev/null
```

suppresses all output.